# twitter api not working simple command

Tags: python, api, twitter, social-networking, tweets

I am trying to extract tweets from a user using python. It is 3 lines of code, but python is giving me a hard time.

```
>>> import twitter
>>> api = twitter.Api()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    api = twitter.Api()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Api'
```

and the final line of code would be:

```
>>> status = api.GetUserTimeline('username')
```

how do I fixed that 2nd line's error. I have python 3.2.2.3

Comment: The twitter API has recently changed so that authentication is mandatory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to authenticate first:

```
api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='consumer_key',
                  consumer_secret='consumer_secret',  
                  access_token_key='access_token',   
                  access_token_secret='access_token_secret')
```

The consumer key, consumer secret, access_token, and access_token_secret are found on the Twitter Development Page: https://dev.twitter.com/apps

Use it to create a fake app and it'll give you the information you need.

If you need more help, here is website: https://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/

Cheers

Comment: I did that as follows:

api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='vzpF0LKea5c6DECWLnoINQ',
                  consumer_secret='3rzfmW2X7bMCmY7wkOMQaIBrzRz0jTzeJnGm0r5D2c',  
                  access_token_key='1517563807-75iFGXWHxMvzzsqrIs5W4tCb4OwFG4eisnDYRst',   
                  access_token_secret='uLhhITppA9CDPyAiP7pkSgJMh45FL3X3F1jiwBBoI')

and it still gives the error

Comment: The only thing I can think of is the twitter api is not in your path.